# why there is a difference between first and second socket request in my nodejs code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Here is my echo server code

```
var net = require('net')                                                           

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('recv data: ' + data);
        socket.write(data + ' random data');
    }); 
    socket.on('end', socket.end);
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

This is the test code

```
var net = require('net');                                                          

var client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(1337, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.destroy();
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');    
});
```

When I first run the client after the server starts, terminal show:

```
➜  test node client.js 
Connected
Received: Echo server

Connection closed
```

I can see the server has send the data to client in wireshark,but client send a RST packet to server immediately after this packet.

the second is normal

```
➜  test node client.js
Connected
Received: Echo server
Hello, server! Love, Client. random data
Connection closed
```

Comment: FWIW `socket.on('end', socket.end);` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in output is just due to a race condition. Sometimes the server is able to (receive and) send more data before the socket is actually completely closed, other times not.

Comment: I can see server has send the echo data in wireshark.Is it possible that the client did not receive it?

Comment: That is what I mean. The server may have sent it, but not before the client's operating system closed the socket and rejected/dropped any traffic received afterwards.

Comment: Client can receive echo data after remove `client.destroy();`,